# How to fast-load YouTube embeds keeping 1-click play on mobile phones also?

Tags: javascript, php, mobile, youtube-api, embed

Embed codes like Labnol's described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41240594/how-can-i-remove-youtube-links-with-this-alternative-embedding-method-not-ifra), require 2 clicks to play the embedded video from mobile phones, as Labnol clarifies from the start.

Is there another solution that achieves both:

1. One-click to play user experience
2. Fastest load speed of web page with embedded video

YouTube embeds on [theguardian.com website](https://github.com/guardian/frontend) seem to achieve this, as in [this](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2018/aug/05/powerful-earthquake-strikes-indonesia-killing-at-least-three) example:
[image]

When the page loads you don't see the default YT player, but rather a cover with a red play icon. Once you click anywhere on the thumbnail the video plays immediately - as opposed to just remove the cover, show the YT player from which you would have to click the Play button again.

What code achieves the same? This is the code they use on the page:

```
    <div data-media-atom-id="29a2a152-66e2-47b8-be0e-9da8336ecfa3" class="u-responsive-ratio u-responsive-ratio--hd youtube-media-atom" data-end-slate="/video/end-slate/section/world.json?shortUrl=https://gu.com/p/95a3f" data-unique-atom-id="29a2a152-66e2-47b8-be0e-9da8336ecfa3/0">
<iframe id="youtube-4USNqImit7w" data-asset-id="4USNqImit7w" class="youtube-media-atom__iframe youtube__video-ready" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" title="YouTube video player" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4USNqImit7w?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;embed_config=%7B%22adsConfig%22%3A%7B%22nonPersonalizedAd%22%3Afalse%7D%7D&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.theguardian.com&amp;widgetid=1"></iframe>
<div class="vjs-big-play-button youtube-media-atom__overlay" style="background-image: url(https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/2424c0e0c381810c343a342388ed374218068b83/0_270_5184_2916/5184.jpg?w=700&amp;h=394&amp;q=55&amp;auto=format&amp;usm=12&amp;fit=max&amp;s=071c90178b02212b1c1684615c3a9f7f)">
<div class="youtube-media-atom__play-button vjs-control-text">
Play Video
<span class="inline-play inline-icon ">
<svg width="46" height="39" viewBox="0 0 46 39" class="inline-play__svg inline-icon__svg">
<path d="M46 20.58v-2.02L1.64 0 0 1.3v36.55L1.64 39 46 20.58z"></path>
</svg> </span>
</div>
<div class="youtube-media-atom__bottom-bar">
<div class="youtube-media-atom__bottom-bar__duration">
0:45
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The same behavior can be observed in video embeds at the [bottom](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/asia/2011/05/20115235148217423.html#bottomvideo) of Al Jazeera's articles, although the embedded player is not YT.

Comment: Have you checked out LazyFrame? I'm using it for my projects. https://github.com/vb/lazyframe

Comment: It might be something as simple as the embedded youtube video having `autoplay` turned on? _<iframe width="620" height="349" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4USNqImit7w" frameborder="0" allow="**autoplay**; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>_